# Filter an echoed table using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I need help with regards to filtering my echoed table using javascript. I'm just using a  as a refresher of my form. Take a look on my code below.

Here's my code for the filtering

```
<div align="center">
        <?php
          // Connect to server and select database.
          mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

          mysql_select_db("leavecalendar") or die(mysql_error());
          $i=0;
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM employee");
          $storeArray = Array();
          echo '<label>Filter By Name:</label><select name="fullname" style="width: 200px">';

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
              echo "<option >".$row['fullname']."</option>";
          }

          ?>
          </select>
          <!--Filter by Date -->
          <label>Filter By Date:</label>
            <input class="datepicker">
            <a href=""id="refresh">click</a>


      </div>
```

Here's my code for the echoed table

```
                  <div style="height:70%;">
                  <?php
                      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
                      // Check connection
                      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                      {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }

                      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE id='$row[fullname]'");
                      ?>

                      <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="width: 897px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock In</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock Out</strong></td>

                    <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualstart']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualend']; ?></td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>


                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                </div>
```

All in all there 2 codes are under 1 form only. So below is the summary of the codes for your reference.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="deleteleave.php">  
    <div align="center">
        <?php
          // Connect to server and select database.
          mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

          mysql_select_db("leavecalendar") or die(mysql_error());
          $i=0;
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM employee");
          $storeArray = Array();
          echo '<label>Filter By Name:</label><select name="fullname" style="width: 200px">';

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
              echo "<option >".$row['fullname']."</option>";
          }

          ?>
          </select>
          <!--Filter by Date -->
          <label>Filter By Date:</label>
            <input class="datepicker">
            <a href=""id="refresh">click</a>


      </div>              
            <div class="gridbody">

              <div style="height:70%;">
                  <?php
                      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
                      // Check connection
                      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                      {
                      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                      }

                      $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE id='$row[fullname]'");
                      ?>

                      <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="width: 897px;">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  class="form-table">
                    <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock In</strong></td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock Out</strong></td>

                    <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualstart']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualend']; ?></td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </table>


                      </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input name="endorse" type="submit"   id="endorse" value="Endorse Selected Leave/s">
```

And here's my javascript for refreshing the page. Pratically, I dont want to refresh the whole page but instead I want to refresh the form only so as to display the echoed table filtere by the dropdown or the datepicker. Hope you get my point there.

Code for refreshing the page.

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#Container").load()
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Thank you for all the answers you will give. Much appreciated.

Comment: consider placing the creation of the dynamic content in a separate php-file and load it dynamically on update

Comment: I would like to ask for a sample sir as I'm so new in javascript. Thank you

Comment: You'll have to use ajax to reload the page without actually hitting 'refresh'.

Comment: Can I ask sir for a sample since I'm also new to ajax. Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code do something like this: 
Make a file echoed_table.php and put in (your code):

```
              <div style="height:70%;">
              <?php
                  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","leavecalendar");
                  // Check connection
                  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                  {
                  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                  }

                  $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timekeeping WHERE id='$row[fullname]'");
                  ?>
                  <table width="10%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" style="width: 897px;">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"  class="form-table">
                <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock In</strong></td>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdclass"><strong>Clock Out</strong></td>

                <?php
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                ?>

                <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['fullname']; ?></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualstart']; ?></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $row['actualend']; ?></td>

                </tr>

                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </table>


                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
            </div>
```

Than in order to load/update the table make the ajax call (maybe including additional (filter) url-parameters):

```
$.ajax('echoed_table.php').success(function(data) {
   $('.gridbody').innerHtml(data); // better use an id to identify the container div, instead of the class here
  });
```